# Два разных цикла объединенные в один

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Нужно разделить два цикла (чтобы они выполнялись независимо друг от друга) и далее вставить их в INSERT запрос sql.
Ломаю голову, не знаю как сделать.

Полностью код вот тут: http://pastebin.com/qY5hDpxZ и ниже в спойлере

```
<form action="" method="post">  
<table>
<tr>
<td>Параметр 1</td>
<td>Тег 1</td>
<td>Параметр 2</td>
<td>Тег 2</td>
<td>Параметр 3</td>
<td>Тег 3</td>
<td>Параметр 4</td>
<td>Тег 4</td>
<td>Параметр 5</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" value=' '/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="mass[]"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tag[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="taggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="masssss[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tagggg[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="massssss[]" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>



<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Поехали!"><br>  

</form>  
<?php  

$arr1 = array_diff($_POST['mass'], array(''));
$arr2 = array_diff($_POST['masss'], array(''));
$arr3 = array_diff($_POST['massss'], array(''));
$arr4 = array_diff($_POST['masssss'], array(''));
$arr5 = array_diff($_POST['massssss'], array(''));

$tag1 = array_diff($_POST['tag'], array(''));
$tag2 = array_diff($_POST['tagg'], array(''));
$tag3 = array_diff($_POST['taggg'], array(''));
$tag4 = array_diff($_POST['tagggg'], array(''));


$proverkakategoriy=mysql_query('SELECT virtuemart_category_id, category_name  FROM  ak89e_virtuemart_categories_ru_ru WHERE  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[0].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[1].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[2].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[3].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr1[4].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[0].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[1].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[2].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[3].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr2[4].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[0].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[1].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[2].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[3].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr3[4].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr4[0].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr4[1].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr4[2].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr4[3].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr4[4].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr5[0].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr5[1].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr5[2].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr5[3].'" )
    AND  INSTR(CONCAT(category_name), "'.$arr5[4].'" )
    ');       

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($proverkakategoriy))
{
    echo '<p style="color:blue;">Совпадения: '.$row['virtuemart_category_id'].' '.$row['category_name'].'</p>';
    echo '<p style="color:red;">Есть совпадения, скрипт не сработает</p>';
}


if (mysql_num_rows($proverkakategoriy)==0){
    foreach($arr1 as $word1) {
        foreach($arr2 as $word2) {
            foreach($arr3 as $word3) {
                foreach($arr4 as $word4) {
                    foreach($arr5 as $word5) {
                        foreach($tag1 as $teg1) {
                            foreach($tag2 as $teg2) {
                                foreach($tag3 as $teg3) {
                                    foreach($tag4 as $teg4) {
                                        echo 'INSERT INTO ak89e_virtuemart_product_categories (category_name,<br>
                                        tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4,<br>
                                        customtitle,<br>
                                        metadesc,<br>
                                        metakey,<br>
                                        category_description ) VALUES ('.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.',<br>
                                        '.$teg1.','.$teg2.','.$teg3.','.$teg4.',<br>
                                        "Купить '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.' в интернет-магазине  - цена, описание, фотографии, характеристики",<br>
                                        '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.' купить в интернет магазине с доставкой, гарантией. Смотрите на сайте фотографии, описание, полные характеристики, отзывы. ,<br>
                                        '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.',<br>
                                        "В разделе '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.' нашего интернет-магазина вы найдете подробное описание, отзывы, цены. Для удобства мы предоставили полные характеристики, фотографии, похожие и сопутствующие товары. Будем благодарны, если вы оставите свой отзыв о товарах. Купить '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.' вы сможете по привлекательным ценам на нашем сайте."
                                        )<br><br><br>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: массивы генерируются следующим образом http://prntscr.com/e5btx6   http://prntscr.com/e5btlp

Comment: но здесь **9** циклов, а не два

Comment: мне нужно чтобы $word и $teg работали отдельно. при данном раскладе сначала дублируется $word и "перемножаются" $teg, а как только $teg "перемножились они начинают дублироваться и начинает "перемножаться" $word

Comment: я не силен в терминологии да и в php )  но думаю, что задача ясна

Comment: в конечном результате хочу получить INSERT в таблицу в поле ХХХ, значения word1+word2+...word5, teg1+teg2+...teg4

Comment: Мне кажется вам с **этим** кошмаром вряд ли кто поможет. Потому что это тихий ужас. Даже не представляю сколько по времени это вообще выполняется и как это работает. Но вам явно нужен рефакторинг.

Comment: работает быстро) и правильно) если нужно все изменить - я не против) перемножение у меня должно работать следующим образом http://prntscr.com/e5cawn . слова для перемножения должны вбиваться в input text. что предложите сделать?

Comment: Если не умеете код форматировать здесь, то хоть скиньте его в pastebin.com или github(gist) ... По вашим картинкам никто разбираться не станет. У вас сложность алгоритма сейчас n^9 т.е. 100 элементав, и система будет думать очень долго...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qY5hDpxZ

Comment: А что именно вы пытаетесь сделать? Простым языком в 2-х 3-х предложениях?

Comment: вбивать в input-ы слова как тут http://prnt.sc/e5cawn и перемножать. таких форм должно быть две. результаты они должны вставляться в INSERT запрос

Comment: Holy shi-......

Comment: @Риад как я понял из скриншота, вбиваем 3 столбца со словами и записываем в базу только уникальные слова для каждого столбца?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте переписал код, я к сожаления (скорее к счастью) не понял что он делает:

- не понял зачем тут столько переменных от `arr[1,5]` и `tag[1,5]`
- Странный запрос к базе `ak89e_virtuemart_categories_ru_ru`и зачем такое условие? И хочу заметить что переменный не экранированы и есть место `sql injection`, и посоветовал бы переписать хотя-бы с использованием `mysqli` и сборкой запросов, можно почитать [здесь](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).
- Ну и зачем столько циклов?

Ну и как я понял из скриншота что это штука работает как-то так: вбиваем 3 столбца со словами и записываем в базу только уникальные слова для каждого столбца

---

> В данном примере также можно использовать `sql injection`

Мне кажется что-то подобное решение должно помочь (НО Я СОВЕТУЮ ПЕРЕПИСАТЬ КОД):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($proverkakategoriy)==0){
    foreach($arr1 as $word1) {
        foreach($arr2 as $word2) {
            foreach($arr3 as $word3) {
                foreach($arr4 as $word4) {
                    foreach($arr5 as $word5) {
                        echo 'INSERT INTO ak89e_virtuemart_product_categories (category_name,<br>
                        tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4,<br>
                        customtitle,<br>
                        metadesc,<br>
                        metakey,<br>
                        category_description ) VALUES ('.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.',<br>';

                        foreach($tag1 as $teg1) {
                            foreach($tag2 as $teg2) {
                                foreach($tag3 as $teg3) {
                                    foreach($tag4 as $teg4) {
                                        echo $teg1.','.$teg2.','.$teg3.','.$teg4.',<br>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        echo '"Купить '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.' в интернет-магазине  - цена, описание, фотографии, характеристики",<br>
                        '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.' купить в интернет магазине с доставкой, гарантией. Смотрите на сайте фотографии, описание, полные характеристики, отзывы. ,<br>
                        '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.',<br>
                        "В разделе '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.' нашего интернет-магазина вы найдете подробное описание, отзывы, цены. Для удобства мы предоставили полные характеристики, фотографии, похожие и сопутствующие товары. Будем благодарны, если вы оставите свой отзыв о товарах. Купить '.$word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3.' '.$word4.' '.$word5.' вы сможете по привлекательным ценам на нашем сайте."
                        )<br><br><br>';

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

проверка стоит для определения нет ли совпадений в базе со значениями в input.
 ваш вариант подходит только для вывода echo, а мне нужно будет делать цельный INSERT запрос в базу, не знаю как это реализовать.
 http://prnt.sc/e5cawn 
 слова слева направо проходят по всем вбитым input-ам, не должно быть дублей